# ElegantNumberButton value is always 0

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the value of the elegant number button but when inserting into sqlite database, the value is always zero. What could be the problem here?

```
final TextView item_price = view.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
            final ElegantNumberButton numberButton = view.findViewById(R.id.number_button);
            final Button btnAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

            item_price.setText(price);
            final String number = numberButton.getNumber();

            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Database database = new Database(getBaseContext());
                    Orders orders = new Orders();
                    orders.setItemId(Integer.parseInt(item_id.toString()));
                    orders.setItemName(name.toString());
                    orders.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(item_price.getText().toString()));
                    orders.setItemQuantity(Integer.parseInt(number));
                    orders.setCustomerName(userInfo.getKeyName());
                    if (database.addToCart(orders)){
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(FoodDetailsActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);

                        startActivity(intent1);
                        finish();
                    }


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the number from within an `OnClickListener` on the `ElegantNumberButton` instance. For example:

```
final TextView item_price = view.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
final ElegantNumberButton numberButton = view.findViewById(R.id.number_button);
final Button btnAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

item_price.setText(price);

String number;

numberButton.setOnClickListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        number = numberButton.getNumber();
    }
});

btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Database database = new Database(getBaseContext());
        Orders orders = new Orders();
        orders.setItemId(Integer.parseInt(item_id.toString()));
        orders.setItemName(name.toString());
        orders.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(item_price.getText().toString()));
        orders.setItemQuantity(Integer.parseInt(number));
        orders.setCustomerName(userInfo.getKeyName());
        if (database.addToCart(orders)){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(FoodDetailsActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent1);
            finish();
        }


    }
});
```